# Display info about GitHub commits

Tags: github-api, discord.js

So, I have a discord bot, and one of the commands I'm hoping to use is to keep the user up to date on the latest update on a game I'm making on github, my question is, is there a way to grab the name and description of the latest commit?

I would assume it uses superagent but beyond that I'm lost.

Comment: Why don’t you use webhooks instead?

Comment: Are you looking for a command that tells you only the last commit or something that sends you a message after every commit? In the second case, as pointed out above, a webhook would be way easier

Comment: I haven't learned anything about webhooks yet, but I was mostly thinking of the former, though the other option sounds appealing too ^ ^

Comment: If you want to use webhooks I recommend you to read [this tutorial](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/228383668-Intro-to-Webhooks) by Discord, it does the exact thing you need. If you need something else tag me in another comment (write @ and then click my name, in this way I get notified) ;)

Comment: maybe this project can help you?
https://github.com/nodejs/github-bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use webhooks to post every commit to a specific channel.

To do that, I've posted the tutorial from [Discord](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/228383668-Intro-to-Webhooks) here.
(To get images by the tutorial, look at the Discord tutorial.

> 1. Get the webhook URL for the server/channel you want to receive messages:
>
> In my server, I've created a text channel labeled #gitupdates. I want
> my repo updates to post messages here, so I'll grab the webhook URL
> for this channel:
>
> 2. Add the webhook URL into your GitHub repo settings
>
> Choose the repository that you'd like to get updates from in your
> Discord server. Once you've selected the repo, go into the settings >
> webhooks menu:
>
> Sweet. Click the "Add webhook" button, and enter the Discord-generated
> URL in the "Payload URL" blank.
>
> **To make the webhook display messages properly, it's really important that you append '/github' at the end of
> it.**
>
> In addition to the URL, you have
> some more GitHub-specific options to choose from. For content type,
> stick with application/json. Discord's webhook format really likes
> JSON. In the next section, you can choose to customize what kind of
> events trigger webhook messages.
>
> Click the last "Add webhook" button beneath the event notifications
> customization option, and you're all set! Pushing any updates in the
> repo (including editing the readme file) will show up in your text
> channel:
>
> And you're all set!

Comment: As much as this is promising, is there a way to have a custom discord bot spit out the webhook information? :B sorry to bother you...

Comment: You can make a bot that's storing all data gathered from the last webhook. So you redirect the webhooks to your bot and your bot is storing the last gathered information from the webhook. Then when you use a command, you can see the information from the last commit. It's an interested thing and I'll try to work it out in discord.js.

Comment: thanks ^ ^ let me know please if you make any progress. ^ ^